# why nginx server_name matches example.com when it is not setup as that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, server-name

Based on my understadning of the doc, server_name decides which server block will be used.

I have an AWS EC2 instance, and my nginx setup is like the following, where I just simply want to redirect all http requests to https. However, my server_name was mistakenly setup as the following instead of example.com.

```
server {
  listen         80;
  server_name    ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.example.com;
  return         301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

However, when I go to http://example.com, I do get redirect to https://example.com, I wonder why that is happening, shouldn't nginx fail to match my http request to that server block since the server_name is not example.com?

Comment: Because that's how nginx's choose server block. It uses best match for port. If there is only one server block, it will be used. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: Good explanation on Digital Ocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#how-nginx-decides-which-server-block-will-handle-a-request

Comment: Thank you, that explains everything ! Thanks !